# ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence - wrong number of arguments - in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, exception, activerecord

To suppress ActiveRecord logging temporarily I use following construction:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence
    #Some ActiveRecord query
end
```

and it works in development Rails environment, but in production raises an exception:

> Exception(ArgumentError): wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)

What is the missing argument and why such a difference between environments?

Comment: Can you provide the whole trace? Also, keep in mind that this is deprecated: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/silence/class

Comment: @sebkomianos: 1. What else do you expect to see in trace? There is no more useful info. 2. Ok, this construction is deprecated, but what to use instead?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `do`.

The syntax is:

```rb
ActiveRecord::Base.logger.silence do
  # Some ActiveRecord query
end
```

Comment: This is an abandoned question. Author has no longer anything to do with the topic and can neither approve nor decline your answer.

Comment: I guessed as much since this is from 2014, but might as well help future developers that run into the same issue.